# AWK/Sed string manipulation

Tags: sed, awk

I have a string in the following format and I want to convert it to csv format (note the separator is the underscore character "_"

`Title_YYYYMMDD_emailname` convert to `Title,YYYYMMDD,emailname`

This is simple enough using sed ...

```
echo "Report_20131107_jlsmith" | sed 's/_/,/g'
```

Output:

```
Report,20131107,jlsmith
```

But there are complications trying to parse a string that contains underscores in the title field ..
I want to retain the underscores in the title (if any) but change the underscores to commas for the
date and emailname ...

For instance:

```
Report_Title_20131107_jlsmith convert to: Report_Title,20131107,jlsmith
```

And a related question: is there a way to compress multiple repeating instances of the underscore character for the entire string?

```
Report_Title____20131107_jlsmith convert to: Report_Title,20131107,jlsmith
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last request first:

```
echo "Report_Title____20131107_jlsmith" | awk '{gsub(/_+/,"_")}1'
Report_Title_20131107_jlsmith
```

---

First request (using `gnu awk`)

```
echo "Report_Title_more_20131107_jlsmith" | awk '{print gensub(/_([0-9]+)_/,",\\1,","g")}'
Report_Title_more,20131107,jlsmith
```

---

All in one command

```
echo "Report_Title___more_20131107_jlsmith" | awk '{gsub(/_+/,"_");print gensub(/_([0-9]+)_/,",\\1,","g")}'
Report_Title_more,20131107,jlsmith
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed -r -e 's/_+/_/g' -e 's/_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$/,\1,\2/'
```

Or more robust with stringent regex

```
sed -r -e 's/_+/_/g' -e 's/^(.+)_([0-9]{8})_(\w+)$/\1,\2,\3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the format you have shown, you could replace `____YYYYMMDD_` with `,YYYYMMDD,` using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) as follows

```
echo 'Report_Title____20131107_jlsmith' | sed 's/__*\([0-9]\{8\}\)__*/,\1,/g'
Report_Title,20131107,jlsmith
```